# Is it possible to add an entry value to the entry URL Format?

Tags: url, slug, entry

I try to compose an entry URL for artists pages with first name and last name.

Now:

```
artists/{slug} = artists/{{ entry.title }}
{slug} = {{ entry.title }} = Artist Last Name
```

What I want to add at the end of the URL (Plain Text field):

```
{{ entry.artistFirstName }} = Artist First Name
```

What I try to get, but which is not working:

```
artists/{slug}-{{ entry.artistFirstName }}
```

Is it possible? how? And how can I add a conditional to check if *entry.artistFirstName* is defined?

Thanks!

Comment: you could just have the URL in your template any way you like ("/template/slug/firstname/lastname") and then just use the {slug} when fetching the entry from the database. An idea.

Comment: I don't know if I well understood, but I tried to add something like {% set slug = "/entry.artistFirstName/entry.title/" %} in the template requested to display this page but this didn't affect the URL.

Comment: I was thinking you leave the URL setting as is in Craft (like "artists/{slug}" for example). Then when creating the links in Twig just make them "/artists/{slug}/{entry.artistFirstName}". In your template when just fetch the single entry using segment #2. Could that work for you?

Comment: Thanks! I created a link like <a href="{{entry.artistFirstName}}-{{ entry.url }}"> that works, but of course the link points to a page that does not exist and generates an error 404. How can I just fetch the {{ entry.url }} segment and continuing to display the full URL I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this a good approach is to use the excellent Dynamic Routing system in Craft.

### Solution #1

First create your section "Artists":

[image]

After that go to "Settings" -> "Routes" and add this Dynamic Route:

[image]

When this is done all URL requests made to "/artists/-whatever-" will be routed to the "artists/_entry" template. Now you can create your link like this:

```
<a href="/artists/{{ entry.slug }}/{{ entry.firstNameField }}/{{ entry.lastNameField }}">Artist Name</a>
```

Your URL might now look like this rendered:

```
<a href="/artists/ladygaga/firstname/lastname">Lady Gaga</a>
```

In your "_entry" template you can now fetch your entry using this code:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('artists').slug(craft.request.getSegment(2)).first() %}
Artist Name: {{ entry.title }}
```

### Solution #2

If you instead want the URL to be "/artists/firstname-slug" you can alter the Dynamic Route slightly and use the Twig filter "split" to get the slug from the URL.

First change the Dynamic Route to:

```
artists/*
```

Then update your template "_entry" with the following code:

```
{% set segments = craft.request.getSegment(2)|split('-') %}
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('pages').slug(segments[1]).first() %}
Title: {{ entry.title }}
```

Your URL can now be "/artists/{{ entry.firstNameField }}-{{ entry.slug }}" and the template code will take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks! After after few adjustments, it finally works for me. But is there a way to get an URL like /firstname-lastname instead of /firstname/lastname? I tried some Routes with **-** instead of **/** but got 404 errors or wrong pages.

Comment: Just make the route "/artists/*/*" instead and make the URL "/artists/slug/firstname-lastname" in your template. Will be the same result :)

Comment: As explained in my request: lastname = slug. So I'm trying an url like this: /artists/firstname-slug (to get something like /artists/lady-gaga, where gaga is the title of my entry = the slug). Unfortunately that does not work like this.

Comment: Please see my edited post @Romainpoirier on how to make a URL the way you want it. Please accept my answer if you feel it's the right one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanations! Now it works perfectly for me! :-)

Comment: Just one more question: how would you do to avoid _'%20'_ spaces in first segment if _artistFirstName_ is composed of more than one word? I already have an **| upper** filter, and tried to add **| join**, **| url_encode** or **| replace** filters but failed to find the correct solution.

Comment: A "|replace" filter with " ", "-" should work. No?